# Blocking locks on org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader

Tags: java, multithreading, crystal-reports

I did some profiling using JMC on my web application executing Crystal Report hoping to find some clues why the report is generating slowly. I ran 2 report generation requests and found some thread contention issues on the API.

The underlying method which invokes the API is a static method and uses static variables (Method is highlighted in red)

How can I determine the cause of the contention?

[image]